# Android: How to save an instance of parcelable object?

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-notifications

I am trying to save an instance of `StatusBarNotification`, so that i could show the notification later to the user. I noticed that `StatusBarNotifcation` is not `Serializable` but `Parcelable`. Is there any way to store the exact instance state in the database so that even if user turns of his phone, the instance object is stored.

I know its not the best practice to store the `Parcelable` object in database. But I need to do it.

If there is any way i could get the byte array of the instance, I am open for suggetions.

**EDIT**

I found out today that, if I turn off my android phone with some un-attended notification, when I restart my phone I am still able to see the same notifications. That being said, android is somehow saving the same instance of notification.

Now my question is, how?? And if android does why can't us.

Comment: If you really cannot avoid it (JSON serialization is often an idea), you can use [`writeToParcel()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html#writeToParcel%28android.os.Parcel,%20int%29) followed by [`Parcel.marshal()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcel.html#marshall%28%29) which gives you the raw byte stream for the parcel. But really: Read the warning there.

Comment: Did you manage to find any solution? I have spent a lot of days but failed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you cannot save the parcelable object of notification in the database (also not a good practice).

Answer (score 4):

> Is there any way to store the exact instance state in the database so that even if user turns of his phone, the instance object is stored.

No. In particular, not only do you have no way of persisting the `PendingIntents` associated with the `Notification`, but you have no way of recreating them with all the security rules intact. A `PendingIntent` is tied closely to the app that creates it; you are not the app that created those `PendingIntents` originally.