# How to use JSONCreator to serialize

Tags: serialization, android-pendingintent, json-deserialization

I came across this class on Github that serializes a pendingintent: 
https://github.com/8tory/json2notification/blob/master/json2notification/src/main/java/com/bluelinelabs/logansquare/typeconverters/PendingIntentConverter.java
Can anyone tell me how to use the serialize function with the JSONCreator object

Comment: why you want to serialize PendingIntent?

Comment: @DaveRanjan I need to save it, so that I can launch it later through the app I'm developing. These pendingintents belong to push notifications from other apps.

Comment: Believe me you can't store pending intents of other app notifications. I was also trying to do so. Here is my question > http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33920125/android-how-to-save-an-instance-of-parcelable-object

Comment: but there is a work-around. :P

Comment: What is the work-around? @DaveRanjan

Comment: first, you need to tell me, what is your use-case. Because, with my workaround, that notification will not belong to other app anymore, but you will be able store notification and all the actions belonging to it.

Comment: The use-case is simple, I want to be able to redirect the user to the same place that clicking the original notification would have redirected him to. But the redirection will happen from the app I am creating @DaveRanjan

Comment: Do you also want to dismiss the original notification?

Comment: That's not a concern currently @DaveRanjan

Comment: okay, give me sometime, i will post a gist and share the link over here.

Comment: Thanks a lot @DaveRanjan

Comment: Any updates? @DaveRanjan

Comment: Hey @DaveRanjan any updates?

Comment: Sorry dude, i tried the logic but it doesn't seems to be working. Basically idea was reposting notification content as your own notification but with low priority. But there are two major issues in that, first notifications will vanish when phone restarts and second, user will be able to see the duplicate notifications.

Comment: It worked in my case bcoz, i had overridden the notification panel itself, so user was not able to see duplicate notifications.